# How can I make consuming custom events on my classes optional?

Tags: c#, events, event-handling

When I comment out the `fm.OnLoaded` line below, it gives me an error that OnLoaded is null.

**How can I make it optional for the caller of my class to consume the event or not as with .NET classes / events?**

```
using System;
using System.Windows;

namespace TestEventLoaded8282
{
    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            FileManager fm = new FileManager();
            //fm.OnLoaded += new FileManager.LoadedHandler(fm_OnLoaded);
            fm.Load();
        }

        void fm_OnLoaded(object obj, FileManagerArgs args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("the file manager is loaded: " + args.Message); 
        }
    }

    public class FileManager
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public delegate void LoadedHandler(object obj, FileManagerArgs args);
        public event LoadedHandler OnLoaded;

        public FileManager()
        {}

        public void Load()
        {
            Name = "this is the test file manager";
            OnLoaded(this, new FileManagerArgs("no errors"));
        }
    }

    public class FileManagerArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public string Message { get; set; }

        public FileManagerArgs(string message)
        {
            Message = message;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if (OnLoaded != null) {
    OnLoaded(this, new FileManagerArgs("no errors"));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Check for null before invoking the delegate. The following is a common pattern:

```
public event EventHandler<FileManagerEventArgs> Loaded;

public void Load()
{
    ...
    OnLoaded(new FileManagerEventArgs("no errors"));
}

protected virtual void OnLoaded(FileManagerEventArgs e)
{
    EventHandler<FileManagerEventArgs> handler = this.Loaded;
    if (handler != null)
    {
        handler(this, e);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 This is the typical way to write event handlers, at least from what I've seen. I like having the separate OnLoaded method in case there needs to be additional logic before/after an event handler is fired.

Answer (score 3):

You need to check that the `OnLoaded` event handler is not `null` before invoking it:

```
LoadedHandler handler = OnLoaded;

if (handler != null)
{
    handler(this, new FileManagerArgs("no errors"));
}
```

You will need to do this every time you invoke an event handler. The local `handler` variable above is to catch the case where you can check that the handler is non-null, but something removes the handler before you call it. Creating a local variable captures the handler to prevent this.

An alternative approach is to define the event handler as:

```
public event LoadedHandler OnLoaded = delegate{};
```

This declares a default empty event handler, making the null check redundant (there is a slight performance loss using this approach though).